# How to find a project within the TFS 2010 Source control?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

I have some project A which is checked in to some folder within the Team Project long time back by somebody else. I have to where it is located. do i have any command to search the file or project file within the team project. I have many team projects within the project collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're searching for a file and know the name of it, you can do it from the commandline (Visual Studio Command Prompt) using tf.exe.

```
tf dir $/TeamProjectName/FileName.csproj /recursive /s:http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/CollectionName
```